# PostgreSQL trigger execute if one column has changed ignoring certain columns

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am creating an audit table using the PostgreSQL trigger function below

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION company_change_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN
    IF OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW THEN
        INSERT INTO history.companies(name, email, logo, phone_number, alt_phone_number, company_id) VALUES (OLD.name, OLD.email, OLD.logo, OLD.phone_number, OLD.alt_phone_number, OLD.id);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

the problem is the table with the trigger has `updated_at` field that changes whenever a row is updated which is causing `OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW` not to work so **is it possible to ignore the `updated_at` column when checking if the row has actually changed using `IS DISTINCT FROM`?**

if not what other way could i achieve this other than checking each individual column separately which could get cumbersome on a table with more than a few columns.

**thanks in advance**

Comment: You will need to list all columns: `if (old.c1, old.c2, old.c3) is distinct from (new.c1, new.c2, new.c3) then ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion but this tends to get unmaintainable for a large number of columns

Comment: You could temporarily change the `updated_at` column, then compare, then reset it.